# unsupported format character '%' error as I try to create logs

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to create a simple log file using the following code.

```
import logging

format = '%(asctime) %(message)'

logging.basicConfig(format=format)
log_message = {'service': 'test-service', 'm': 'service started successfuly!'}
logger = logging.getLogger('root-logger')

logger.warning('this is a test log message %s', extra = log_message)
```

But as I try to execute the above code, I get an error saying:

```
    --- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/pc/anaconda3/envs/spider/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1025, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
File "/Users/pc/anaconda3/envs/spider/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 869, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
File "/Users/pc/anaconda3/envs/spider/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 611, in format
    s = self.formatMessage(record)
File "/Users/pc/anaconda3/envs/spider/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 580, in formatMessage
    return self._style.format(record)
File "/Users/pc/anaconda3/envs/spider/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 422, in format
    return self._fmt % record.__dict__
ValueError: unsupported format character '%' (0x25) at index 11
Call stack:
File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    logger.warning('this is a test log message %s', extra = log_message)
Message: 'this is a test log message %s'
Arguments: ()
```

I cannot understand the error.What could be the reason for this error?

Comment: Your format is missing the `s` for string. `format = '%(asctime)s %(message)s'` makes for much nicer logs ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two issues:

1) Your formatting string is missing the `s` after `%(...)`

2) Your logging call is missing the required argument corresponding to `%s`

Try this:

```
import logging

format = '%(asctime)s %(message)s'

logging.basicConfig(format=format)
log_message = {'service': 'test-service', 'm': 'service started successfuly!'}
logger = logging.getLogger('root-logger')

logger.warning('this is a test log message %s', 'msg', extra=log_message)
```

This'll print

```
2019-10-08 12:45:28,991 this is a test log message msg
```

So what happened to your `extra`? Well your format didn't have any places to put them, so they didn't show up. To make your extra data show up, you formatter must have places for **each key in the dict**

```
format = '%(asctime)s %(message)s | %(service)s - %(m)s'
```

Will print:

```
2019-10-08 12:50:30,189 this is a test log message msg | test-service - service started successfuly!
```

Here's the relevant documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug

Comment: How can the viewer differentiate if this was a warning log? Also, is there a way with python to append to a file?

Comment: You need to add the `%(level)s` format specifier to get the log level in the message. And checkout different handlers for writing to files. Specifically the FileHandler: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#filehandler

Answer (score 1):

"%s" means that a string is expected as a positional argument. So you should supply a string that will substitute the "%s":

```py
logger.warning('this is a test log message %s', 'service started successfully!')
```

Here's an example if you want to use "extra":

```py
import logging

# "service" and "m" are extra arguments so you need
# to supply them inside the "extra" dictionary with every log entry.
format = '%(asctime)s %(service)s %(m)s %(message)s'
# (Note the "s" after the brackets that specify a string)

logging.basicConfig(format=format)
log_message = {'service': 'test-service', 'm': 'service started successfuly!'}
logger = logging.getLogger('root-logger')

logger.warning('this is a test log message', extra=log_message)
```

Resulting:

```
2019-10-08 10:19:00,310 test-service service started successfully! this is a test log message
```